# GeoJSON coordinates are displaying incorrectly on map

Tags: postgis, leaflet, geojson, react

I am setting up my first Leaflet map with react / node / PostgreSQL and have managed to get to the level where I have pulled the geojson form my PostgreSQL database. However from what I can see the lat and lng look like they are the wrong way around when they get rendered.

Can anyone see if there is anything obvious I have to change to get the markers to display correctly?

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Layer, Marker, Popup, useMapEvents, Map, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';

//import mapData from "../test/mapData.json";
import L from "leaflet";
import icon from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
import iconShadow from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png";

import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
//import mapData from "../test/mapData.json";
import { pullScubaSchools } from "../actions/scubaSchool.action";
import "../App.css";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";


//Layer.geoJSON(pullScubaSchools).addTo(ScubaDivingMap);


export class ScubaDivingMap extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            schoolList: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        pullScubaSchools().then((response) => {
            const { data } = response;
            this.setState({ schoolList: data.data });
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.schoolList.length > 0) {
            console.log("list", this.state.schoolList);
        }

        let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: icon,
            shadowUrl: iconShadow,
        });

        return(
            <container maxWidth="sm">
            <div>
                <Typography
                    component="h1"
                    variant="h2"
                    align="center"
                    color="textPrimary"
                    gutterBottom
                >
                    Diving School Map
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    variant="h5"
                    align="center"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    paragraph
                >
                    List of approved Sustainable Scuba diving schools offering our courses and recommended by our staff.
                </Typography>
                <container>
                <MapContainer
                    center={{ lat: 41.505, lng: -0.09 }}
                    zoom={3}
                    scrollWheelZoom={false}
                >
                    <GeoJSON
                        //style={this.countryStyle}
                        data={pullScubaSchools.diveSchoolGeo}
                        //onEachFeature={this.onEachCountry}
                    />
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    {this.state.schoolList.length > 0 &&
                    this.state.schoolList.map(({ diveSchoolGeo }) => {
                        console.log("diveSchoolGeo", diveSchoolGeo.coordinates);
                        return (
                            <Marker position={diveSchoolGeo.coordinates} icon={DefaultIcon}>
                                <Popup>
                                    {diveSchoolGeo}
                                </Popup>
                            </Marker>
                        );
                    })}
                </MapContainer>
                </container>
            </div>
            </container>
        );
    }
}

export default ScubaDivingMap;
```

Comment: What does your GeoJSON look like?  Is it valid?  Are the coordinates in the correct order: `[longitude, latitude]`?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It seems you solved your original question, and so you completely changed it to a new question. If you have a new question, please post it as a new, separate question. Your modification was rolled back to original question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by marking the coordinates with array numbers and setting them into the correct order for the rendering into leaflet. Another way would be using the leaflet method 'l.geojson.coordstolatlngs()' to switch the lat and lng coordinates.

```
{this.state.schoolList.length > 0 &&
                    this.state.schoolList.map(({ diveSchoolGeo }) => {
                        console.log("diveSchoolGeo", diveSchoolGeo.coordinates);
                        return (
                            <Marker position={[diveSchoolGeo["coordinates"][1], diveSchoolGeo["coordinates"][0]]} icon={DefaultIcon}>
                                <Popup>
                                    {diveSchoolGeo}
                                </Popup>
                            </Marker>
                        );
                    })}
```